# IOS UIProgressView bar is not updating, can anyone tell why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, uiprogressview

I started messing around with the UIProgessbar and then I started having issues with it not updating the view.

Here is my code in view did load:

```
progressViewBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                                              cameraBarOverlay.frame.size.height + cameraBarOverlay.frame.origin.y,
                                                              self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                              10.0f)];

[progressViewBorder setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress_bg"]]];

progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 5.0f);
progressView.transform = transform;
[progressView setFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f,5.0f,progressViewBorder.frame.size.width,1.0f)];
[progressView setProgressTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[progressView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[progressView setProgress: 0.0f];
[progressView setProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
[progressView setTrackTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[progressViewBorder setHidden:YES];
[progressViewBorder addSubview:progressView];
[self.view addSubview:progressViewBorder];
```

Here is my updating code:

```
- (void)startMovieRecording:(id)sender {
[[self recordButton] setEnabled:NO];
CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(15, 50);
[[self movieFileOutput] setMaxRecordedDuration:maxDuration];

dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
    if (![[self movieFileOutput] isRecording]) {

        [self setLockInterfaceRotation:YES];

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
            [self setBackgroundRecordingID:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil]];
        }

        // Update the orientation on the movie file output video connection before starting recording.
        [[[self movieFileOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoOrientation:[[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[self previewLayer] connection] videoOrientation]];

        // Turning OFF flash for video recording
        [FTCamViewController setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff forDevice:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];
        [toggleFlash setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[flashImages objectAtIndex:2]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        currentFlashMode = [flashImages objectAtIndex:2];

        // Start recording to a temporary file.
        NSString *outputFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"movie" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"]];
        [[self movieFileOutput] startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath] recordingDelegate:self];

        while ([[self movieFileOutput] isRecording]) {
            double duration = CMTimeGetSeconds([[self movieFileOutput] recordedDuration]);
            double time = CMTimeGetSeconds([[self movieFileOutput] maxRecordedDuration]);
            CGFloat progress = (CGFloat) (duration / time);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
            });
        }

    } else {
        [[self movieFileOutput] stopRecording];
    }
});
```

}

Can anyone tell why this wouldn't be updating?

Comment: It's not updating because you are blocking the UI thread with your `while` loop.

Comment: I updated my code to see if it helps, I am not sure if this is the problem. When I initialize the UIProgressView in ViewDidLoad it isn't updating properly, instead it is taking up the 50% of the width it is taking up 100%. This makes me think something else is going on since I am trying to hardcode the 50% just for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is really bad but it turns out that I had the tint color and progress tint color set to the same.. whiteColor. This was causing the display to act very strange.

Here is what solved it for me.

```
[self.progressView setProgressTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.progressView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[self.progressView setProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
[self.progressView setTrackTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

From looking around for possible solutions I updated my while loop to this:

```
while ([[self movieFileOutput] isRecording]) {
            double duration = CMTimeGetSeconds([[self movieFileOutput] recordedDuration]);
            double time = CMTimeGetSeconds([[self movieFileOutput] maxRecordedDuration]);
            CGFloat progress = (CGFloat) (duration / time);

            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress]];
}
```

And my selector does the updating.

```
- (void)updateProgress:(NSNumber *)progress {
    [self.progressView setProgress:[progress floatValue] animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your while code in a separate method. Call this method with

```
[self performSelectorOnBackgroundThread....]
```

add a method to Update the Progress Bar andcfall this method from your while method by

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread....]
```

Claus

Comment: Why? Using GCD is more elegant. This is not a correct answer.